# If $\sin(x)/\sin(y) = \sin(9)/\sin(18)$, can we say that $y = 2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am not really sure whether trigonometric functions work like that, and if we can say that, how would you prove that?

Comment: We simply cannot.

Comment: I see, so if x/y= 1/2, that doesn't necessarily mean sin(x)/sin(y) = 1/2?

Comment: No. We could say $\sin x / \sin y = 1/(2 \cos x)$ though.

Comment: apply the double angle formula on the RHS to simplify it.

Comment: $50 / 100$ is $1/2$ but $sin(50) / sin(100)$ is `0.5181529558935164` in radians and `0.7778619134302059` in degrees.

Comment: No, of course not. That implication would only make sense with functions of the form $kx$.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: You can surely say $\sin(y)=\sin(x+9)-\sin(x-9)$ that is, obviously, true for $x=9$ and $y=18$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle is that you can not "cancel" function symbols, i.e., in general,

$$
\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}\color{red}{\ne}\frac{x}{y}\tag{1}
$$

Your particular case is $f(u)=\sin(u)$.

Try more simple examples to convince yourself:
$$
f(u)=2u+1,\quad f(u)=u^2,\quad \cdots
$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x = 2y$ then
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(2x)} = \dfrac{\sin(9)}{\sin(18)}$$

Which means, by using $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$,

$$x = \arccos\left(\dfrac{\sin(18)}{2\sin(9)}\right) \approx 2.716$$

Hence

$$y = \dfrac{\sin(x)\sin(18)}{\sin(9)} = -0.75234$$

From which you can see $y \neq 2x$

Comment: Shouldn't we have $x \approx 2.716 + 2n \pi $ for some $n$?

Comment: @user56202 Yes, that would be better indeed! I focused on the first solution :)

Comment: Haha I see :) $ $